# select all ids where the only difference is the number in the ID name

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have all these **divs with an identical ID** name except for the fact that they all have a different number at the end.

I know I can use a class but it must be an ID.

```
    <div id="myid1">text</div>
    <div id="myid2">text</div>
    <div id="myid3">text</div>
    <div id="myid4">text</div>

   <div id="test1">text</div>
   <div id="test2">text</div>
```

My question is using css how can I select them all but shorter than this .

```
#myid1,#myid2,#myid3,#myid4{
    color:red;
}
```

Does this type of thing exist and if so how do you write it?

```
myid1[*]{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use classes?

Comment: it must be IDs - this is just a basic example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use the prefix attribute selector

```
[id^="myid"] {

}
```

This selector targets any element with an ID attribute that has the prefix "myid" - quotes around the value are optional. This selector works in IE7 & above as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [begins with this attr selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

```
[id^=myid] {
    color:red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7va6M/)

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 should help here:

```
div[id^="myid"]
```

AND

```
div[id^="test"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way

```
<div id="myid1" class="foo">text</div>
<div id="myid2" class="foo">text</div>
<div id="myid3" class="foo">text</div>
<div id="myid4" class="foo">text</div>

<div id="test1">text</div>
<div id="test2">text</div>
```

and css

```
.foo { color:red; }
```

## UPDATE

If those have to be IDs, try with `[id^=myid]`

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work a lot better for you to use classes as incremental ids goes against HTML and general programming principles.  You could rewrite it like so:

```
<div class="myid" data-id="1">text</div>
<div class="myid" data-id="2">text</div>
```

However, if you *must* keep the `id`s as they are, you can use the attribute selector:

```
[id^=myid] {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: "incremental ids goes against HTML and general programming principles"? Why do you say this? The html spec states that no particular meaning should be derived from the id attribute, so incremental IDs seems fine to me. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @xec IDs are supposed to identify unique elements, so if elements are related by some kind of data you would have to parse the id string (e.g. take out the `myid` part to get the actual ID value).  You should be parsing the attribute itself (as in `data-id`).

Comment: Granted, if you are using the numeric part of the ID in a script later on, having only the numeric part of the ID by itself in a separate attribute is much cleaner to work with. However, if you want to link to (or scroll to) a specific section of a generated page, incremental IDs is a good option. (just link to "#myid2" for instance). Of course this is all circumstantial and only the OP knows why they need to be IDs... i am merely curious what the source of your statement is.

Answer (score 1):

In your case this would do it:

```
[id=^"myid"] {
    //your rules
}
```

That selects all elements whose id attribute begins with "myid".

You're not limited to the id attribute though. In fact, you could use any other html element's attribute.

Let's say you wanted to select all <a> tags whose "href" attribute begun with "http://stackoverflow.com". The following would do it:

```
a[href=^"http://stackoverflow.com"] {}
```

There's really a ton of options. Instead of pointing them out myself I'll you link to the w3 page where all of it is detailed: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors

Answer (score 0):

use classes in addition to the ids (if you really need the ids):

```
<div class="mytext" id="myid1">text</div>
<div class="mytext" id="myid2">text</div>
<div class="mytext" id="myid3">text</div>
<div class="mytext" id="myid4">text</div>

<div id="test1">text</div>
<div id="test2">text</div>
```

then the CSS is simple:

```
div.mytext {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*any id that contains shelf*/

div[id*= 'shelf']{
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="apple-1shelf">30 days</div>
<div id="orange-1shelf">30 days</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).